# JOOQ: mark column as "deprecated"?

Tags: jooq

I'd like to somehow mark a column in my schema as "deprecated" (probably as some kind of tag in the column comment or something), and then have that info bubble up through the code generation process to result in an `@Deprecated` annotation being added to the fields/methods for that column in the generated code.

Does JOOQ have any functionality related to that?
Browsing through the user manual doesn't seem to show anything relevant.

Comment: AFAIK, no. The closest thing you can get right now is hiding the columns: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.12/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-includes-excludes/. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: @PetrJaneček I think it's an acceptable workaround for my specific case - but I can see how marking columns would, yeah.  Excluding the column from generation and adding a comment to the column would probably get most of the way toward my current use-case - since I do just want to stop using the column entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using the jOOQ 3.15 synthetic comments feature

Starting from jOOQ 3.15, you can use the [synthetic comments feature from the code generator](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-comments/), e.g.

```xml
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.16.0.xsd">
  <generator>
    <database>
      <comments>
        <comment>
        
          <!-- Regular expression matching all objects that have this comment. -->
          <expression>CONFIGURED_COMMENT_TABLE</expression>
          
          <!-- Whether the comment is a deprecation notice. -->
          <deprecated>true</deprecated>
          
          <!-- Whether the original schema comment should be included. -->
          <includeSchemaComment>false</includeSchemaComment>
          
          <!-- The actual comment text. Defaults to no message. -->
          <message>Do not use this table.</message>
        </comment>
      </comments>
    </database>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```

#### Hack using SQL comments

Use this hack (if your RDBMS supports comments):

```sql
COMMENT ON COLUMN my_table.my_column IS '@deprecated';
```

It won't produce the annotation, but it will produce equivalent Javadoc, which has the same effect in IDEs.

Comment: Cool. Why do you call it a hack?  This is pretty much what I was hoping JOOQ would do but I didn't see it in the manual.

Comment: @Shorn: It's a hack, because it "happens" to work this way and is not designed for that purpose. Comments generate Javadoc. The fact that this has the desired effect for you is not intended, nor will it be documented. It's also a hack because it suggests to abuse database columns for this purpose, when in fact, they are intended for documenting things inside the database, and for any other client.